# Who am I? I'm not really sure

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> *Add an "e", and I'll be impure*
>   *Add an "f", you'll have to be careful*
>   *Reunite me with my ex, and I'll go up and down out of control*
>
> > It's not exactly a reverse hangman.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you be the word

> **or**

Add an "e", and I'll be impure

> **ore** -  a mixture of rock and mineral, so not pure.

Add an "f", you'll have to be careful

> Then add f to get **fore** - shouted in golf as a warning to watchout for a flying ball.

Reunite me with my ex, and I'll go up and down out of control

> Your ex meaning something which has been cast i.e. discarded, thrown away.
>
>  Joining this gives **forecast** - a financial or weather forecast is unpredictable.
>
>  *Edit (thanks to @DrunkWolf): Add an "x" to Fore at the end and you have **Forex**, the foreign exchange market that moves up and down out of control.

The title;  I'm not really sure

> Or is an option or choice, so not one certain thing.

Comment: Probably on the right path, but your 'ex' seems weird; I'm quite sure you should google Forex to find something that goes up and down out of control ;)

Comment: Possibly, I'm not sure about relating x and ex, and maybe the answer would then be the exchange rate.

Comment: @DrunkWolf is right! Just wanted to make that sentence more "meaningful"